# Annotate based on calculation in ManyToManyField

Tags: django, manytomanyfield, annotate

I am trying to annotate a Django model by calculating a non-trivial expression using a property of a `ManyToManyField` in the model.

The situation can be translated into the following simple example structure of "payments" that should be split between a number of "companies" according to their relative sizes. Which companies participate in a given payment is stored as a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Company:
  relative_size = models.DecimalField()   ## can be assumed to add up to 1 among all companies

class Payment(models.Model):
  companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name='payments', blank=True)
  amount = models.DecimalField()
```

I'm now trying to query for the total amount that each company participated in. If the share was the same in each of the payments, this would be as simple as

```
companies = Company.objects.annotate(total_payments=Sum(F('payments__amount')*F('relative_size')))
for company in companies:
  print("Company %s: %s" (str(company), total_payments))
```

But how to do this in the case where I have to calculate the correct fraction for every payment based on which companies participated? I suspect I have to use `Subquery` but couldn't really adapt the examples in the documentation to my case.

PS: As a workaround I have implemented this in "Python" instead of in queries as follows:

```
payments_annotated = Payment.objects.annotate(sum_involved_companies_sizes=Sum(F('companies__relative_size')))
companies = Company.objects.all()
for c in companies:
  c.sum = Decimal('0.0')
  for p in payments_annotated.filter(companies__id=c.id):
    c.sum += p.amount * c.relative_size/p.sum_involved_companies_sizes
```

But I guess this must be possible and more efficient within the queries system, so I'm hoping an expert can help out? Thanks!

Comment: For every payment, the related companies `relative_size` will equal `1`?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, for every payment the `sum(relative_size)` can be different from `1` because not all companies participate in each payment. That's why I think I need this `SubQuery` to calculate the "total size" that participates in each payment.